# Pattern Recognition?

Tags: image-processing

First of all am not even sure if my problem is a pattern recognition problem or feature identification. Am not an expert in image processing but otherwise here is my problem.

Am making an application that has to identify the type of lightning in a series of images. Am using C++ with OpenCV for image processing. By thresholding the images I am able to get the lightning part of the image. What I need to do next is to identify whether the lightning is branching upwards as shown in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaWe1.png

or whether its branching downwards as shown in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sYcd.png

These are the basic shapes of branching that the application has to identify from a series of images. Now my problem is that I don't know how to implement this functionality of identifying the direction of branching from an image. All I need is to be steered into the right direction as to what approach I could take to implement this. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Long time since I used OpenCV so I am going to outline only the approach I immediately thought of.

1. Find all line segments.
2. For each line segment find its direction (is it going up, or down?). You might have to be clever about deciding which is the start and which is the endpoint, but it should be pretty easy I think. You could probably find some heuristic based on branching points...
3. Average the result to find out if most of the segments are going downwards or upwards.
4. Done.

**EDIT: Update on point 2**
Assume that you have a list of line segments where each segment is a continuous line without branching. That is, you can't have a Y-shaped segment, only I-shaped.

1. For each segment, find its endpoints (p1, p2) where pX=(x,y).
2. For x=[1,2] determine if pX is a branchpoint (a point which is shared with another line segment) or an actual endpoint. Call the branchpoint pB and and the endpoint pE.
3. Calculate the vector between the points as d = pE - pB. If the y-value of d is positive then you have a upwards pointing branch. If you want, use d to calculate the declination of the line between the two points and use that as measurement instead of just the binary option of either up or down.

Finding the endpoints (and branching points!) should be pretty easy using different morphological operations.

Comment: thank for the guideline kigurai. for step 2,how would i go about finding the direction of the line segments?

Comment: thanks once more, but how do i perform morphological operations dont you have any good links to this?

Comment: Check the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_image_processing which is however a bit mathematical. Otherwise any book on image processing worth its name should have a section about this.

Comment: kigurai how can I go about finding the line segments of the image in OpenCV? Been trying to figure this out but it seems am wasting my time, please guide me.

Comment: Sorry, for specific OpenCV questions I am of little use since it was a few years since I used it. Check the documentation for functions that speak of segmentation or lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a more intuitive way.

0) Upon looking at your pictures, i can see that the acute angles(angle < 90) in between the branches can be associated with your 'upward' / 'downward' orientation

1) for the 'up' image, you can first find all the acute angles in between the branches and see if they are 1-180 (up to you, or you can refine this to any values between 0-180)

2) for the 'down' image, you can then find all the acute angles in between the branches and see if they are 181-360.  (up to you, or you can refine this to any values between 180-360)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

An easy-to implement algorithm would be, to get all branchpoints and endpoints (morphology). Now, if you remove branchpoints, given that you don't have circles in your image you get (topologically) lines - one end is an endpoint and one is a brancpoint. Segmentate your line segments, then put back branchpoints. Now you can calculate the branchpoint-to-endpoint vector for all line segments. The dot product with (0,1) will show that the given line segment points upwards, or downwards.

Comment: thanks for the guide but the thing is am new to OpenCV and I dont know how to do any morphological operations, dont you by any chance know any links to good tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You should also take into consideration that there could be lightning that is horizontal (from cloud to cloud). Except if you know for certain this is not going to be present in your dataset.

If it is, you probably want to use a threshold for the declination mentioned in kigurai's answer.

Another more tricky problem you might have is when your picture-set has pictures of lightning at broad daylight. Overexposed parts of the image are probably as bright as the lightning itself, and then your initial thresholding step will give some noise.